# How to solve $\int_{x}^{x+a} f_X(u) du=e^{-2\lambda_1 x} \int_{x-a}^{x} f_X(u) du$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

How to solve equation of the type
\begin{align*}
\int_{x}^{x+a} f(u) du=e^{-\lambda x} \int_{x-a}^{x} f(u) du
\end{align*}
we want to solve for $f(x)$ where $\lambda,a$ are some constants.

Things I tried
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{x+a} f(u) du= \frac{d}{dx} e^{-\lambda x} \int_{x-a}^{x} f(u) du\\
f(x+a)-f(x)= -\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \int_{x-a}^{x} f(u) du+e^{-\lambda x} (f(x)-f(x-a))
\end{align*}

But how to proceed next? Should, I take derivative one more time? But I don't think this will lead anywhere and plus we would have to assume that $f(x)$ is differential.

@Drone Scientist suggested that we can take derivative with respect to $a$. However, since $a$ is constant I am not sure if it is allowed?

Thank you

Comment: I have no answer to your questions but I suggest starting instead with the derivative with respect to $a$.

Comment: But $a$ is a constant. I guess I didn't mention that. I will add.

Comment: Differentiating with respect to $a$ one obtains $f(x+a) = -e^{\lambda x} f(x-a)$ which is a [functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation) defining a type of function.  I could not find a solution to this type of functional equation in lists of standard functional equations.

Comment: @DroneScientist Is there a table of functional equations with solutions? If so could point me to it?

Comment: Please see the wikipedia link as a start.  (I'm not sure if I'm actually helping or just giving you nonsense though!)

Comment: @DroneScientist I think good discussion is always helpful.  Thanks a lot for caring